# 3 Div column classes from a Foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I'd like to get this code to actually work.
What I'm trying to get is my items separated into 3 columns.

I would also like to call the columns "first", "second", and "third", instead of
class0, class1 and class2

This code isn't working since all my items get called class0

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
$count = $count == 3 ? 0 : $count++;
?>

<div class="<?php echo "class".$count ?>">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
if ($count==0) {
    $class  = "first";
    $count++;
} else if ($count==1) {
    $class  = "second";
    $count++;
} else {
    $class  = "third";
    $count = 0;
}
?>

<div class="<?php echo $class ?>">
```

Something like this should work though a select case may be quicker

Answer (score 2):

No need for the `== 3` test, a simple:

```
<div class="classs<?php echo $count++ % 3?>">
```

would do the trick. Modulo math:

```
$count = 0 -> 0 % 3 = 0
$count = 1 -> 1 % 3 = 1
$count = 2 -> 2 % 3 = 2
$count = 3 -> 3 % 3 = 0
$count = 4 -> 4 % 3 = 1
etc...
```

You code is not working because `$count++` is returning count's first FIRST, then incrementing the value. But since that original value is returned and assigned back to $count, you continually assign 0 over and over and over.

If you'd done `++$count`, then it would have worked. (increment THEN return the new value)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php
  $count = 0;
  $names = ['first','second','third'];
  foreach ($this->items as $item) :
?>
<div class="class-<?=$names[$count++%3] ?>">
<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these codes:

1st way:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
$count = $count == 3 ? 0 : $count++;
    switch ($count){
        case 1: echo "<div class='first' >";break;
        case 2: echo "<div class='second' >";break;
        case 3: echo "<div class='third' >";break;
    }
}
```

?>

2nd way:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$name = null;
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
    $count = $count == 3 ? 0 : $count++;
    $name = ($count == 1 ) ? 'first': ( $count == 2 ) ? 'second': 'third';
}
?>

<div class="<?php echo $name ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays with hard coded values like :

```
<?php
$numbers = array('first','second','third');
foreach ($this->items as $item):
  $count = $count == 3 ? 0 : $count++;
?>
<div class="<?php echo "class_".$numbers[$count] ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```